# GameplayKit: Enemy agent overshoots destination point during seek behavior

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I'm trying to incorporate GameplayKit into a SpriteKit project.

Specifically, I'm trying to use GameplayKit's seek-and-avoid behavior wherein an "enemy" character chases a moving "player" character while avoiding obstacles.

I have managed to make the enemy seek the player, but the enemy's movement is weird/undesirable: The enemy's speed should adjust so that it comes to a halt at the desired end point, however its speed does *not* change, which makes it overshoot its target considerably.

Think of a fast-moving train: Once it gets up to speed, it's hard to stop; it wants to just keep on moving. It's the same phenomenon with the enemy character sprite. It moves like a heavy, lumbering object that can't stop quickly enough.

Here's what I'm doing (please assume that properties such as `node` are defined):

1. Configure the player character's GameplayKit stuff:

```
let entity1 = GKEntity()
heroAgent = GKAgent2D()
heroComponent = GKSKNodeComponent(node: node)
heroAgent.delegate = self
node.entity = entity1
heroEntity = entity1
if let comp = heroComponent {
    entity1.addComponent(comp)
    entity1.addComponent(heroAgent)
}
```

2. Configure the enemy character's GameplayKit stuff:

```
let entity = GKEntity()
let agent = GKAgent2D()
let avoid = GKGoal(toAvoid: obstaclesForThisLevel!, maxPredictionTime: 1000.0)
let pursue = GKGoal(toInterceptAgent: heroAgent, maxPredictionTime: 0.0)
nodeComponent = GKSKNodeComponent(node: node)
agent.maxSpeed = 100.0
agent.maxAcceleration = 50.0
agent.position = vector_float2(x: Float(levelData.enemies[i].x), y: Float(levelData.enemies[i].y))
agent.radius = Float(node.size.width*0.5)
agent.behavior = GKBehavior(goals: [avoid, pursue], andWeights: [100.0, 100.0])
agent.delegate = self
node.entity = entity
enemyAgent = agent
if let comp = nodeComponent {
    entity.addComponent(comp)
    entity.addComponent(agent)
}
nodeEntity = entity
```

3. In the `SKScene`'s `update(_:)` method, set the player agent's position and call the enemy character's `update(deltaTime:)` method:

```
//Coordinate the hero agent's position with the hero's actual position. Without this, the values in agentDidUpdate() are nan.
heroAgent.position = vector_float2(x: Float(mainCharacter?.position.x ?? 0.0), y: Float(mainCharacter?.position.y ?? 0.0))
nodeComponent?.node.entity?.update(deltaTime: currentTime-lastFrameTime)
```

4. Set the enemy character's position in `agentDidUpdate(_:)`:

```
func agentDidUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent) {
   if let a = agent as? GKAgent2D {
      nodeComponent?.node.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(a.position.x), y: CGFloat(a.position.y))
   }
}
```

Question: Why is the enemy character overshooting its designated target point instead of managing its speed correctly, and how do I fix the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to only use GameplayKit for the purpose of generating a path around the obstacles (`findPath(from:to:)` is very helpful), and to simply move the enemy character along that path via `SKAction.follow(_:asOffset:orientToPath:speed:)` when I want to send the enemy back to its starting position.

So, to accomplish the "seeking" behavior, I'm just doing the following from inside my `SKScene`'s `update(_:)` method:

```
let dx = mainCharacter.position.x - enemy.position.x
let dy = mainCharacter.position.y - enemy.position.y
let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
let vx = cos(angle) * enemySpeed
let vy = sin(angle) * enemySpeed

enemy.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = vx
enemy.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = vy
```

This seeking behavior does *not* consider obstacles, so the enemy *can* get kind of stuck behind an obstacle that's located between the enemy and the player. So, it's not ideal, but I think it's going to work for me because of other factors in my game.

To generate a path that *does* consider obstacles, for use with `SKAction`, I'm doing the following:

```
let graph = GKObstacleGraph(obstacles: obstaclesForThisLevel, bufferRadius: 0.0)
let startingPoint = GKGraphNode2D(point: vector_float2(x: Float(enemy.position.x), y: Float(enemy.position.y)))
let endPoint = GKGraphNode2D(point: vector_float2(x: Float(enemy.enemyOriginalPosition.x), y: Float(enemy.enemyOriginalPosition.y)))
graph.connectUsingObstacles(node: startingPoint)
graph.connectUsingObstacles(node: endPoint)
let path = (graph as GKGraph).findPath(from: startingPoint, to: endPoint)

if path.count >= 2 {
    let realPath = GKPath(graphNodes: path, radius: 100.0)
    let myPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()

     for j in 1..<realPath.numPoints {
          let previousPoint = realPath.float2(at: j-1)
          let nextPoint = realPath.float2(at: j)
          if j == 1 {
              myPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(previousPoint.x), y: CGFloat(previousPoint.y)))
          }
          myPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(nextPoint.x), y: CGFloat(nextPoint.y)))
      }
}
```

And finally:

```
let followPath = SKAction.follow(myPath.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, speed: enemySpeed)

enemy.run(followPath)
```